# Robotframework WebDriverException issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm new to robot framework and have been trying to run this script.

```
*** Settings ***
    Library         SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=Nothing
    
    Test Setup       Open Browser And Go To Page
    Test Teardown    Close Browser
     
    *** Variables ***
    ${FORM_URL}         https://www.google.com/
    ${BROWSER}          headlesschrome
     
     
    *** Test Cases ***
    Page Should Show Header
        Page Should Contain     Google 
     
    *** Keywords ***
    Open Browser And Go To Page
        Open Browser    ${FORM_URL}   ${BROWSER}
```

On running the script getting following error:

```
==============================================================================
Testing
==============================================================================
Page Should Show Header :: When visit the page it should show the ... | FAIL |
Setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing                                                               | FAIL |
```

I've tried all the suggested answers on Stackoverflow and till it does'nt works.Tried these bellow and even added driver details on PATH but getting same error.
Current google-chrome version is 96.0.4664
pip 21.3.1
Python 3.7.9

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\Users\win32\96.0.4664.45\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

Comment: Environment variables needs to have the chromedriver

Comment: Have already added Environment variables (i.e PATH)

Answer (score 0):

solution1: Go to Windows environment variables, add the PATH to the chromedriver.exe location to it.

solution2: drag the chromedriver.exe to the location where your .robot files are.
(in VisualStudioCode you can drag from Windows FileExplorer to the location in the menu on the right).

advise: pip install webdrivermanager

read page: https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Windows path "D:\Users\win32\96.0.4664.45\chromedriver.exe"  to 'PATH' variable using Env variables click on OK.
   Try restarting eclipse and laptop/PC on setting up above stuff.
2. Also, you can add chromedriver.exe to your Python path folder >> "...\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"